# Format Date to Year-Month in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to retain my current date column in year-month format as date. It currently gets converted to chr format. I have tried as_datetime but it coerces all values to NA. 
The format I am looking for is: "2017-01"

```
library(lubridate)
df<- data.frame(Date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-01-04",
                       "2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-02-01","2018-03-02"),
            N=c(24,10,13,12,10,10,33,45))
df$Date <- as_datetime(df$Date)
df$Date <- ymd(df$Date)
df$Date <- strftime(df$Date,format="%Y-%m")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Date class holds, well, dates, so the best you can do is to set each to the first day of the month. If you really need a year-month class, see `zoo::yearmon`.

Comment: To follow alistaire's suggestion (and the common practice) of setting each date to the first day of the month, run `df$Date <- floor_date(as.Date(df$Date), 'month')` right after creating `df`

Comment: @alistaire: Edited my post to reflect the format I am looking for. zoo::yearmon actually gives me Month name.

Comment: That's just the print methods, which are built for consistency. If you don't like the display format, the usual time to fix it is at the end when assembling presentation plots/tables/whatnot when you can just print strings.

Comment: @Ryan: That was helpful, thank you!

Comment: @alistaire: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`lubridate` only handle dates, and dates have days. However, as alistaire mentions, you can floor them by month of you want work monthly:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_month <-
  df %>%
  mutate(Date = floor_date(as_date(Date), "month"))
```

If you e.g. want to aggregate by month, just `group_by()` and `summarize()`.

```
df_month %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(N = sum(N)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>  Date           N
#>  <date>     <dbl>
#>1 2017-01-01    59
#>2 2018-01-01    20
#>3 2018-02-01    33
#>4 2018-03-01    45
```

Comment: This coerces all date values to NA with a warning message: All formats failed to pass. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Is your date variable exactly the same as in your example? That is, `year-month-date`?

Comment: I got it to work. I didn't floor the date before executing this. Could I use the same floor function to group my dates by week? I used mutate(Date = floor_date(as_date(Date), "week")) but am guessing that is incorrect format?

Comment: Please see the `lubridate` [docs](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html) for rounding dates.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this with zoo::as.yearmon() function. Follows the solution:

```r
library(tidyquant)
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-01-04",
                  "2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-02-01","2018-03-02"),
           N=c(24,10,13,12,10,10,33,45))
df %<>% mutate(Date = zoo::as.yearmon(Date))
```

Comment: Yes, it is not needed, but tidyquant loads zoo package

Comment: All you really need here is `library(zoo); transform(df, Date = as.yearmon(Date))` .

Comment: I´m still curious to see what happens, over here I can´t install the package - I am doing some research to see what is happening with my R in Windows machine - install.packages("zoo")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/j/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Comment: @JoniHoppen: You might need to install tidyquant first because that contains the zoo package.

Comment: @AM_123 Acctually tidyquant is not needed in this case, we could change to library('zoo') and the code should work too.

Comment: I found the problem, I had 2 instances of Rstudio running so after closing both it worked out eventually. Thanks for the support folks. Wish great code out there!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` function, and use `breaks="month"` to transform all your days in your dates to the first day of the month. So any date within the same month will have the same date in the new created column.

This is usefull to group all other variables in your data frame by month (essentially what you are trying to do). However `cut` will create a factor, but this can be converted back to a date. So you can still have the date class in your data frame.

You just can't get rid of the day in a date (because then, is not a date...). Afterwards you can create a nice format for axes or tables. For example:

```
true_date <-
  as.POSIXlt(
    c(
      "2017-01-01",
      "2017-01-02",
      "2017-01-03",
      "2017-01-04",
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-02",
      "2018-02-01",
      "2018-03-02"
    ),
    format = "%F"
  )

df <-
  data.frame(
    Date = cut(true_date, breaks = "month"),
    N = c(24, 10, 13, 12, 10, 10, 33, 45)
  )

## here df$Date is a 'factor'. You could use substr to create a formated column
df$formated_date <- substr(df$Date, start = 1, stop = 7)

## and you can convert back to date class. format = "%F", is ISO 8601 standard date format

df$true_date <- strptime(x = as.character(df$Date), format = "%F")

str(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to weigh in with a base R option:

```
df$year.month <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y-%m")
```