# R: How to remove the day from a date?

Tags: r, data-mining

I have a bunch of dates in a df column in the following format: dd.mm.yyyy

I want it to look like this: 01/2020 (mm.yyyy)

How can I remove the day from all of the dates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format Date to Year-Month in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338191/format-date-to-year-month-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides `format` by [@Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532907/12158757), another option is using `sub` like below

```
> sub(".*?/","","13/01/2020")
[1] "01/2020"
```

Comment: Why should I use a string manipulation/regex when working with dates?

Comment: @mnist Just another way to show the desired result, although it's not ``date` type...

Comment: I have a bunch of different dates in the column, not only 13/01/2020, how can i make the code applicable to all dates in the column? sorry didn't make that clear in my question

Comment: It just looks like an overkill to me when we can just use format. Might still be helpful for OP though

Comment: @mnist the output of `format` is also a character string, not `date` type

Comment: @sjoelly you can try `sub(".*?/","",df$date)`

Answer (score 6):

Use `format` to specify the date format you'd like

```
date <- as.Date("13/01/2020", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
format(date, "%m/%Y")
[1] "01/2020"
```

Edit - applying to dataframe column

```
dates <- c("13/01/2020", "17/02/2015", "13/03/2013")
df <- data.frame(dates, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df$dates_format <- format(df$dates, "%m/%Y")
df
       dates dates_format
1 2020-01-13      01/2020
2 2015-02-17      02/2015
3 2013-03-13      03/2013
```

Comment: I have a lot of different dates in the column, so this code only changes dates matching 13/01/2020, is there any way to make it applicable to all dates in the column??

Comment: @sjoelly - yes, see edit

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)

#Set the desired format (mm-yyyy) as my_stamp
my_stamp<-stamp( "02-2019", 
                 orders = "my") 

#A df with a column full of dates
df <- data.frame(dates = c("30/04/2020","29/03/2020","28/02/2020"))

#Change the column from string to date format
df$dates<-dmy(df$dates)

#Apply the format you desire to the dates (i.e., only month and year)
df$dates<-my_stamp(df$dates)

#    dates
#1 04-2020
#2 03-2020
#3 02-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

There are explicit date formatting options in R (see answer by Greg). Another option would be to separate the date into 3 columns, and then recombine the month and year, putting a / in between.  Note this leaves the new date column in character format, which you may want to change depending on your needs.

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(date = "13/01/2020")
df <- separate(df, date, into = c("day","month","year"), sep = "/")
df$newdate <- paste(df$month, df$year, sep = "/")
```

Comment: Greg's answer should be the accepted answer. the sub and separate options are just other ways to do it.