# How to convert character into date format?

Tags: r, date

I've got a character like this:

"2008-11" and I want to convert it in a date format. (only year and month)

I've already tried with zoo package:

```
yearmon("2008-11")
```

but it returns a NUM. I want a Date as structure. It should return 2008-11.

Which is the fastest way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need `zoo::as.yearmon("2008-11")` ? `"2008-11"` cannot be date since it does not have date.

Comment: `as.Date(paste0('2008-11','-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(anytime)

a <- anydate("2008-11")

> class(a)
[1] "Date"

> a
[1] "2008-11-01"
```

Comment: I don't want to have the day. How can I remove the day? Thanks!

Comment: If you want a Date class you must have the day. You can manipulate how the date is showed using format(), but then it will be converted back to character. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532807/r-how-to-remove-the-day-from-a-date