# How to reformat dates to dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy

Tags: r, date, time-series, format, data-cleaning

Essentially, I just need to drop the extra info provided by the day and month, and only retain the year.
My data is in the form of
dd/mm/yyyy (so, 20/11/2001 for example) and I want to just retain the yyyy (so 2001).

This question and answer: [R: How to remove the day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532807/r-how-to-remove-the-day-from-a-date/61532907#61532907)
have been somewhat helpful, but I have thousands of individual dates and so copying in the exact dates I need to change isn't going to work.
Does anyone have any idea how I can do this??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568070/extract-year-from-date)

Comment: `library(data.table); year(as.Date(c("2020-06-01", "2021-01-10")))`

Comment: In case it is a character you can use `sub`: `sub(".*/", "", YourDates)` or `format(as.Date(YourDates, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")`

Comment: Thank you both so much! This solved the problem, so I've reposted the code below!

Answer (score 1):

Convert to date class, then extract year using *format*:

```
format(as.Date(df1$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y")
```