# How to set data type of column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date, type-conversion

I have columns like these:

```
year       period     period2        Sales
2015       201504     April 2015     10000
2015       201505     May 2015       11000
2018       201803     March 2018     12000
```

I want to change the type of `period` or `period2` column as a date, to use later in time series analysis

Data:

```
tibble::tibble(
  year = c(2015,2015,2018),
  period  = c(201504, 201505,201803 ),
  period2  =  c("April 2015", "May 2015", "March 2018"),
  Sales = c(10000,11000,12000)
)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: at that moment type of these columns is "character" so I need to set them as date because I have another column about sales and need to do a time series analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lubridate` package you can transform them into date variables:

```
   df <- tibble::tibble(
      year = c(2015,2015,2018),
      period  = c(201504, 201505,201803 ),
      period2  =  c("April 2015", "May 2015", "March 2018"),
      Sales = c(10000,11000,12000)
    )
    
    library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
      mutate(period = lubridate::ym(period),
             period2 = lubridate::my(period2))
```

Comment: I found that `lubridate::my(period2)` worked fine as well.

Comment: It works almost fine, but is it possible to avoid "days" in output. because after using this function I have 2015-04-01, so I wish to have only monthly data: 2015-04

Comment: Maybe then you should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338191/format-date-to-year-month-in-r

Comment: I edited my answer with your suggestions @mkpt_uk, much easier solution :)